# How to change default table name `users` to custom name

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.4

I want to change default table name `users` to another name, say `lara_users`.

Searched several resources and many of them says that "you need change table name in `config/auth.php` file like so: `'table' => 'lara_users'`.

In Laravel 5.4, there is not clearly defined (for me at least) where is that `'table'` key? I changed here:

```
...
'providers' => [

    'users' => [
       'driver' => 'database',
       'table' => 'lara_users',
    ],
],
...
```

Though, after that, when I try to log in, application trows an error: `Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist` (I use postgresql).

P.S.

I already changed table name to `lara_users` in `migrations`, it works and creates that table successfully.

Answer (score 7):

If you want to add `lara_` in all the table name then you can add the name by adding prefix in the `database.php`. if you add prefix it will add to all tables and you do not need to change anything else, laravel itself search for the table with this prefix.

```
    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
        'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => 'lara_',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Please note that it will work with eloquent query if you use `DB::table('')`, then you need to add the prefix in all queries. use `$prefix = \DB::getTablePrefix();` for prefix to make it dynamic for DB queries.

Comment: Thanks, but question is about how to use completely new name  for storing users data, not just addidng some prefix

Answer (score 5):

OK. change  users to lara_users in user migration.

Now that you change the default table name. go to User model User.php under

app directory, add this in User class

```
 protected $table = 'lara_users';
```

Now go to RegisterController.php edit the email key:

```
 'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

to this

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:lara_users',
```

That's it.

Comment: `then updated config/auth.php` - How to change? I mean what to change exactly ?

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your `auth.php`

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
        'table' => 'lara_users',
    ],
],
```

After that run artisan migrate command.

If your `App\Users` modal have set `$table` variable then change it to

```
protected $table = 'lara_users';
```

Comment: Though, when trying to authenticate user (I have created default `auth` system using `artisan make:auth`), it still  trows  error: `Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "users" does not exist`.

Comment: @RIKI riki I just edited my answer it works fine I tested before I post!

Comment: open your database, drop all tables manually and execute migrate again.